# Why does my trackpad fire random clicks when I scroll with two fingers?

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, hp-spectre

I have an HP Spectre 360 (model 13-4193nr) running Windows 10.

I noticed that whenever I scroll using two fingers on the trackpad, it scrolls fine, but it also fires unexpected clicks (left clicks) whenever I use it. This happens randomly in all applications. After some testing, I realized that it fires an extraneous click whenever I scroll down and then immediately up, and vice versa. That's only one of the triggers, however; I couldn't tell what the other triggers are after a lot of experimentation. I've also verified my finger movements to make sure I'm not doing any other gestures that are supposed to fire clicks.

This is a bigger problem than I expected because while I can try to prevent my cursor from being near a button I don't want clicked, my trackpad (occasionally, not always) also moves the cursor up and down whenever I scroll, in the opposite direction I scroll (same direction as my fingers). That's probably a separate issue, and I'll likely ask a different question about it.

Also, I don't run into any of these issues when I use my touchscreen to scroll.

Comment: Does your trackpad has support for palm rest?

Comment: @LPChip No, it doesn't.

Comment: @gparyani I'm very familiar with this model. I'm positive it does support palm rest.

Comment: @LateralTerminal SmartSense you mean? I tried disabling that, and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @gparyani I actually have a specter 360. I'm not sure if I have an identical trackpad but I assume they are the same. I don't have the issue you describe. Was this something that happened suddenly or since you've had the computer?

Comment: @LateralTerminal No, it's persisted ever since I purchased the computer. What's your model number? Could I have a defective trackpad?

Comment: @gparyani I don't have access the model number atm. It's possible you have a defective trackpad. I'll be totally honest with you though. I've never been a fan of any trackpad on any computer and mostly use a usb mouse when I'm working on it. I'll do some tests tonight and report back to you.

Comment: @LateralTerminal Good thing they equipped this laptop with a good, high-quality touchscreen, so I can still scroll reliably.

Comment: HP has a wonderful track pad software. If you open it up, it should show your fingers and what they are doing on the track pad. I would watch the visual representation of your fingers while recreating the issue. If you havent already, it may be worth checking the drivers. Sometimes a bug in the driver installation can cause something like that.

Comment: @Alex That's exactly what I used to verify my finger movements. How would I check for a bug in the driver installation?

Comment: start menu, type "devmgmt.msc" then right click it and run as administrator. find the track pad in the list of devices and then right click, properties. Go to the drivers tab, then click on uninstall device. close the properties window and then find "scan for hardware changes" on the top of the devmgmt screen. It should reinstall the driver. Make sure that you have a mouse plugged into the computer BEFORE starting this troubleshooting as you will not be able to use the track pad when the driver is uninstalled. The touch screen should also work fine.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but if you haven't tried turning off tap to click, try turning it off and see if that changes anything. It sounds like it's interpreting the gesture as a tap.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 Nope, did not fix the issue.

Comment: @gparyani Have you attempted reinstalling the trackpad driver. You can do that at https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers.

Comment: @ds_secret Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with the scroll acceleration. Due to the way touch pads work, they detect how many fingers are on them and where they are moving, and then try to figure out what you are doing based on the settings for acceleration and sensitivity. Try playing around with the touch pad acceleration under mouse settings in windows, and maybe turning the sensitivity down. 
Another guess is that when you switch directions, your finger slightly lifts off the touch pad and then goes back down, registering a click. If this is the case, there's not much you can do, other than adjust the sensitivity.

Comment: Did not work. Also, I said in the question that I verified all my finger movements.